# Ошибка ESLint: Cannot find module '@eslint/eslintrc/universal'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, eslint

WebStorm в открытом файле **.eslintrc.js** показывает ошибку

```
Initialization error (ESLint). Cannot find module '@eslint/eslintrc/universal'
```

Долго мучался, но так и не понял из за чего это.
Так же пробовал удалить `node_modules` и заново установить все зависимости, но это не помогло.

p.s. - делаю всё в точности как в этом уроке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0rkLRLU6Dw

Мои файлы:

**.eslintrc.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:eslint-comments/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
  },
}
```

Установленные зависимости **package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
```

Comment: Какую версию Node.js вы используете? Проверьте настройки в **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM**. См. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/14986

Comment: @lena (Node v12.14.1) (npm 8.0.0)

Comment: `eslint@8` requires Node.js `^12.22.0`, `^14.17.0`, or `>=16.0.0`